# Where are gnome extensions preferences stored?

Tags: paths, gnome-shell-extension

Am creating a dotfiles git repo for my gnome setup and would like the precise settings for the Gnome extensions to be transferrable across installations

I found that the extensions themselves are stored in 
`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` directory but I couldn't find the preferences I set in an extension (say [Screenshot Tool](https://github.com/OttoAllmendinger/gnome-shell-screenshot/) for example) inside that directory, it's just Javascript and Style files

What's even more confusing is that in order to watch for changes...

I initialized a git repo on the entire home directory and committed everything for a clean workspace, went and changed a keybinding for the extension but git didn't detect any change via `git diff`

What is going on here? Where can I find a preferences file like an XML or JSON or even `.conf` for an extension?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Schema Files**

The default extension settings are located in an **.xml* file in the following directory if you installed the extension globally:

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/<extension directory>/schemas
```

The default extension settings are located in an **.xml* file in the following directory if you installed the extension locally (which seems to be your case):

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/<extension directory>/schemas
```

In the **.xml* file, the `<key>` tags will list the keys. The `<default>` tags will contain the default values. You could manually edit these files. In order to transfer settings across systems, you will need to update the extension's **.xml* "gschema" file.

In the example extension you referenced above, the settings are located at [Screenshot configurations](https://github.com/OttoAllmendinger/gnome-shell-screenshot/blob/master/res/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.screenshot.gschema.xml).

If you edit these files on your installed system, you will need to recompile the "gschema" by running one of the following commands.

If you had installed the extension globally, execute:

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/<extension directory>/schemas
```

If you had installed the extension locally, execute:

```
glib-compile-schemas ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/<extension directory>/schemas
```

This will create an updated *gschemas.compiled* file in the extension's schema directory.

**Gsettings**

When you change a setting using a GUI (the extension's settings dialog), the change is actually stored in *gsettings*.

You can use *Dconf Editor* to locate the key and value for a particular "gsetting".

Install *Dconf Editor* using:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

(You can also use the `gsettings` commandline tool instead of the *Dconf Editor* GUI tool).

The `<schema>` or `<path>` tags in **.xml* file (as described above) will tell you which schema to navigate to in *Dconf Editor*. (Hint, it will be under `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/`). The **.xml* file will also list which keys can be configured.

You can search for the schema and key in *Dconf Editor*, and make changes.

In my experience, most extension settings are stored in "relocatable" schemas. Effectively, this means you can search for them and change them using *Dconf Editor* only after they have been set at least once. Otherwise the key simply will not be available in *Dconf Editor*, and you will consequently not be able to change its value. This is because the default values from the **.xml* files (as described above) are used when there are no *gsettings* to override them.

Because you want to transfer these settings across installations, try exporting your *gsettings*, and loading them onto your new machine. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056386/how-do-i-backup-all-gnome-tweaks-configuration/1056392#1056392) to another question for instructions. (This approach may be actually easier then editing the **.xml* files, described above).

**Watch for Changes**

A good way to watch for *gsettings* changes, as you make them, is to run the following command:

```
dconf watch /
```

This will show you which schema and key you just changed.

Install the the `dconf` commandline tool using:

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli
```

Comment: Pure gold! exporting the settings and loading them is way better! many thanks

Comment: Thank you! Upvoted. Your answer was really useful in helping me solve my problem here: [How do I reset a Gnome Extension's settings to default? Ex: for "Awesome Tiles" in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446833/327339)--in particular the `dconf watch /` part.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, including when you set the environment variable `GSETTINGS_BACKEND` to `keyfile`, a text file will be created at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/glib-2.0/keyfile`, storing all the extension settings.

This would be useful in developing and testing extensions. For example, in the case of using [this script](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/-/snippets/1060), you can copy the file around to make a reproducable environment for testing.