# Where Gnome extension settings stored

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I've installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS and Gnome. For Gnome I've installed the following extension.
https://github.com/windsorschmidt/disable-workspace-switcher-popup
Works fine after setting the enabled Button to `true` via "Extension" GUI.

But I need to automatize this process without manual user interaction.
Where is the information if the button is enabled or disabled, stored?
I found this thread:
[Where are gnome extensions preferences stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178580/where-are-gnome-extensions-preferences-stored)

But if I look for changes via `dconf watch /` nothing happens.
Additionally I can't find any appropriate key for via `dconf-editor`.

Any Help there?
Would be awesome!

Comment: surely if you install the extension through `Extension Manager` and select the extension on it is persistent?

Comment: I didnt installed the extension via extension manager. For sure its persistent after manual switching. But my goal is an automated installation, so i cant switch it manualy.
The "on" setting must be saved anywhere, thats the point im trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

It's stored in GSettings, use `dconf` (commandline) or `dconf-editor` (GUI) to see/edit them.

List your extensions:

```
dconf list /org/gnome/shell/extensions/
```

Dump the config of the extension:

```
dconf dump  /org/gnome/shell/extensions/fooextension/
```

Set one config value to `30`:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/fooextension/barvalue 30
```

Comment: "dconf list /org/gnome/shell/extensions"
shows nothing, here.

Comment: I've fixed the commands, try again pls.

Comment: Same empty result. Doesn't surprise me because the dconf watch command showed no result too while switching the button.

Comment: what about `dconf-editor`?

Comment: I mean, can you find the path there?

Comment: Noep. There are only default extensions. Not the workspace switcher.
Souldn it be possible to see from here:
https://github.com/windsorschmidt/disable-workspace-switcher-popup/blob/master/disable-workspace-switcher-popup%40github.com/extension.js
Where these setting is saved?